# godaddy smtp data (codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp-auth

I have been trying and failing to get my email configuration working with godaddy. I am using the codeigniter framework (version 3). I even contacted their support but nothing they gave me or i tried worked.

```php
$config['email_address'] = 'no-reply@domain.com';
$config['owner']         = 'name';
$config['email_owner']   = 'no-reply@domain.com';
$config['charset']       = 'utf-8';
$config['mailtype']      = 'html';
$config['protocol']      = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host']     = 'domain.com';
$config['smtp_crypto']   = 'ssl';
$config['smtp_port']     = '465'; // 465, 25
$config['smtp_timeout']  = '7';
$config['smtp_user']     = 'no-reply@domain.com';
$config['smtp_pass']     = 'xxxxx';
$config['validation']    = TRUE;
```

I tried the smtpout.europe.secureserver.net that they provide on the website (not working)

This is the last info i got from their support team. Maybe someone sees something i did wrong.

```
Secure SSL /TLS Settings (Recommended)
Username: no-reply@vbuw.app
Password: email account’s password.
Incoming Server: vbuw.app
IMAP Port: 993
POP3 Port: 995
Outgoing Server: vbuw.app

SMTP Port: 465 IMAP, POP3, and SMTP require authentication.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After calling again to godaddy and getting a diffrent tech support person on the line. We managed to solve the issue.

THIS IS A NONE SECURE (NOT USING SSL) SOLUTION

```
the smtp_host = mail.domain.app
the smtp_port = 587
the smtp_crypto should be removed (so no ssl)
```

So for reference

```php
$config['email_address'] = 'no-reply@domain.com';
$config['owner']         = 'name';
$config['email_owner']   = 'no-reply@domain.com';
$config['charset']       = 'utf-8';
$config['mailtype']      = 'html';
$config['protocol']      = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host']     = 'domain.com';
// $config['smtp_crypto']   = 'ssl';
$config['smtp_port']     = '587'; // 465, 25, 587
$config['smtp_timeout']  = '7';
$config['smtp_user']     = 'no-reply@domain.com';
$config['smtp_pass']     = 'xxxxx';
$config['validation']    = TRUE;
```